# cv2.connectedComponents crashes when called again after printing its result

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv

When calling `cv2.connectedComponents`, printing its result and then calling it again, I get a segmentation fault on the second call.  I managed to narrow it down to the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = np.array([
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
        [255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
        [255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
        [255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
        [255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
        ], dtype=np.uint8)

    res1 = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
    print(res1)
    cv2.connectedComponents(img)  # < here it is crashing
    print("done")
```

When executing it, I get the following output:

```
(2, array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32))
Segmentation fault
```

The especially weird thing: When I remove the `print(res1)`, it reaches the end (printing "done") without error.
Also when I reduce the size of the image, there is no error.

This is happening on a Raspberry Pi with OpenCV 3.3.0.
I cannot reproduce the error on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04, OpenCV 3.3.1).

Is this a (maybe known?) bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, we found out that the issue is caused by the TBB library, it seems to be the same problem as in [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10271).

After recompiling OpenCV without TBB it is working now.  According to the linked issue, compiling with a newer version of TBB may also help but we did not test this yet.